# Django-forms | Error This field is required pero el formulario está completado

Tags: python, django

Al insertar mediante formulario una nueva imagen, me devuelve el error de que "This field is required". Curiosamente el formulario está bien completado. Creo que se refiere al browser donde se selecciona la imagen, ya que se queda como no seleccionado tras darle a guardar. ¿Qué puede estar ocurriendo?

Gracias.

**forms.py**

```
class AddImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ImageStation
        fields = ('__all__')
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AddImageForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['name'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control'})
        self.fields['station'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control'})
        self.fields['image_imageStation'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control'})
```

**add_image.html**

```
<h3 class="text-dark">Insertar nueva foto</h3>
    <form class="" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p}}
        <button class="form-control btn-dark mb-5" type="submit">Guardar</button>
    </form>
```

**views.py**

```
class ImageAddView(LoginRequiredMixin,PermissionRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    permission_required = 'station.update_station'
    template_name = "station/add_image.html"
    model = ImageStation
    form_class = AddImageForm
    success_url = '/station/'
    login_url = reverse_lazy('users_app:user-login')
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para subir un archivo desde una `<form>` y poder recibirlo en el servidor, se debe incluir en dicha `<form>` el atributo `enctype` con el valor `"multipart/form-data"`.

Es decir, solo actualiza tu template para que contenga lo siguiente:

```html
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

De resto, la Class-Based View que herede de `CreateView` se ocupará de lo demás, tal como ya la tienes configurada.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la solución. Funciona perfecto. ; )

Answer (score -1):

Tienes que usar el formData de js para que puedas guardar la imagen entonces cuando le des al boton de guardar haga el post el boton no se mi me entiendes